# Dynamic Click via JavaScript (or jQuery) on a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I know I can change the attribute checked to checked, but i need to actually "click" the checkbox to fire off a live() (jQuery) click event. I know I can also make it a function, but this would just be a lot cleaner and less code, if possible.

Oh, and FYI:

```
$('.modal-form [name='+json[0].owners[x].name+']').click();
```

Doesn't work. It checks em, but doesnt actually "click" them to where jQuery fires the live() event

Here's the AJAX call if anyone is interested:

```
$('.agenda-modal input[type=checkbox]:not([name="emergency-item"])').live('click',function(){
        iid = $('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid');
        the_type = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        checked_item = $(this).val();

        if($(this).attr('checked')){
            if(the_type == 'the-elected-list'){
                $livepreview.agenda({
                    action:'update',
                    type:'owner',
                    id:iid,
                    owner:checked_item
                });
            }
            else if(the_type == 'the-bureau-list'){
                $livepreview.agenda({
                    action:'update',
                    type:'bureau',
                    id:iid,
                    bureau:checked_item
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            $livepreview.agenda({
                action:'get',
                type:'item',
                id:iid,
                callback:function(json){
                    if(the_type == 'the-elected-list'){
                        for(x in json[0].owners){
                            if(json[0].owners[x].name == checked_item){
                                $livepreview.agenda({
                                    action:'delete',
                                    type:'owner',
                                    id:json[0].owners[x].item_owner_id
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(the_type == 'the-bureau-list'){
                        for(x in json[0].bureaus){
                            if(json[0].bureaus[x].name == checked_item){
                                $livepreview.agenda({
                                    action:'delete',
                                    type:'bureau',
                                    id:json[0].bureaus[x].item_bureau_id
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: please include an example. you are most likely not finding the right element by making a complex expression. tone it down.

Comment: @meder well if it's checking the checkbox then he's finding the right element.

Comment: No, like i said, and in the code above, it clicks (and checks the element) but doesn't CLICK the element... theres an AJAX call (ill post in 1 second above) that gets fired when the checkbox is clicked to save the choice on the fly.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I think that before 1.4 (and really 1.4.2 is the "fixed" version of 1.4) event bubbling was a little flaky

Comment: Well a very simple test page suggests that it works - could it be that there's a "click" handler on some parent element, and it's returning "false"?

Comment: @Oscar - try the alert thing I specified. What does it alert?

Answer (score 0):

This will 'click' the checkbox.  I'm not positive if it will fire an event bound with live().

```
$('#myCheck').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

please include an example. you are most likely not finding the right element by making a complex expression. tone it down.

```
var el = $('.modal-form [name='+json[0].owners[x].name+']')
alert( el.length )
```

Then you can `.trigger('click')` it. Make sure the event handler is bound/set.

Comment: For each item I get a "1" returned in the alert. So, if I have two "owners" selected, i get 2 alerts each with "1" returned.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I don't know your code base, but I really wonder whether calling a function by faking UI interaction would be "a lot cleaner".  It might be less code, but it sounds very fragile to me.  What happens when the UI is redesigned?  Or another developer modifies the `live()` event handler without realizing that your code is implicitly using it as well?  Moving the code into a separate function makes it both more legible and more robust (and probably not significantly longer).